# How to customize the switch button according to selected buttion in dialog?

Tags: android

I want to on or off switch buttion according to the dialog pressed butttion.But it work fine when i press yes but it not work when i press No that means swith buttion and dialog is not synchronization according to the  selected option in dialog.Here is my code

```
s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayBasicData.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("make decision");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if(isChecked){
                                        s.setChecked(true);
                                    }

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }

                            });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("ygyu",""+isChecked);
                    if(!isChecked ||isChecked){
                        s.setChecked(false);

                        dialog.dismiss();}

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: on NO you are doing both check and dialog dismiss operation, what you want on NO button ?

Comment: suppose button is Off state and i click the switch buttion it display no and yes in dialog if i click no then also switch buttion is stay in Off state only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some edit on your code, have a look:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayBasicData.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("make decision");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        s.setChecked(true);


                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }

                            });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("ygyu",""+isChecked);

                        s.setChecked(false);

                        dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: it does not work when switch is off when i click on buttton it goes to on state but in dialog when i press NO it display the dialog two times

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 final Switch switch1 =(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

     switch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("make decision");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if((!switch1.isChecked()) ||(switch1.isChecked())) {
                                switch1.setChecked(true);
                            }
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if ((!switch1.isChecked()) || (switch1.isChecked())) {
                        switch1.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: it does not work when switch is off when i click on buttton it goes to on state but in dialog when i press NO it display the dialog two times

Comment: Could you please share your button click. When you want to popup the dialog. is it button click or switch changed?